How do you remove stubborn (album art) / (embedded images) that eyeD3 misses?
How do you remove stubborn (album art) / (embedded images) that eyeD3 misses?
Running:
$ eyeD3 --remove-all-images . #

Works great 90% of the time but not 100% of the time.
I’d prefer a command that removes album art from ALL files in ALL folders. However, doing it one folder at a time as I find lingering album art would work too.

Can you give us any information about the cases and situations where it fails? Something that might help us understand why it is failing?

Nothing stands out... Some m4b files converted to mp3 can prove suborn but are easy to fix. Other than that, some folders just will not clear. As easy as eyeD3 is to use possibly another command would work when it doesn't.
